# Problem with jQuery edit-in-place with live() function.. need a ninja

Tags: javascript, jquery, inline-editing, inplace-editing

This is probably an easy fix, but I am having trouble wrapping my brain around it...

I'm using a jQuery edit-in-place plugin for some divs that will be generated on the fly. It should be simple: Click in the newly created div, and be able to edit the contents. I'm running into problems with live().

Without using live(), it obviously works fine for a static div. Click once, get editable contents.

While using live(), however, I need to **double click** in order to edit the contents. Then any subsequent time it's clicked, it only takes once. It's sorta like a focus issue. Perhaps modifying the plugin itself would help?

Here is exactly what I'm talking about... **http://jsfiddle.net/efflux/62CzU/**

It has something to do with the way I'm calling the editinplace() function with live:

```
$('.editable').live('click',function() {
    //event.preventDefault();
    $('.editable').editInPlace({
        callback: function(unused, enteredText) { return enteredText; },
        bg_over: "#cff",
        field_type: "textarea",
        textarea_rows: "5",
        textarea_cols: "3",
        saving_image: "./images/ajax-loader.gif"
    });  
 });
```

How can get the edit-in-place plugin to function normally on my divs created via js?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty fix: http://jsfiddle.net/62CzU/5/

```
var $this = $(this),
      isInit = $this.data('edit-in-place');
if(!isInit){
    $('.editable').editInPlace({
        callback: function(unused, enteredText) { return enteredText; },
        bg_over: "#cff",
        field_type: "textarea",
        textarea_rows: "5",
        textarea_cols: "3",
        saving_image: "./images/ajax-loader.gif"
    });
    $this.click();
}
```

Comment: Nice.. I was trying to simulate a click event, but had the wrong syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because it's not set up until you click on it. Once you click on it, you set up the EditInPlace which requires it's own click. Just trigger another click after you set it up: http://jsfiddle.net/62CzU/6/

Comment: Nice, thanks man! Still learning, so my syntax is fuzzy, but I was trying every which way to simulate a click.

Answer (score 1):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/62CzU/7/)**

Just change the buttons click to this.

```
$("button.btn").click(function() {
    $(".mydiv").prepend('<div class="passage-marker"><div class="annotation editable">it take 2 clicks to edit me, unless I have already been edited</div></div>');

         $('.editable').editInPlace({
            callback: function(unused, enteredText) { return enteredText; },
            bg_over: "#cff",
            field_type: "textarea",
            textarea_rows: "5",
            textarea_cols: "3",
            saving_image: "./images/ajax-loader.gif"
        });  

    });
}
```

Basically you are just rebinding it every time you create it. The reason you had an issue with `live` is because on the first click it bound it, so then on the second click it was already bound and would work.

Comment: This solution definitely seems less hacky than triggering a click, but it the div guaranteed to exist when the button's click handler is bound?

Comment: Thanks for explaining live() to me... I'm still fairly new to this.  Your solution works great though, I appreciate it!

Comment: Nevermind my comment - I missed that you add the div before you call editInPlace.